# How to allocate memory equal in size to a variable read from an input file?

Tags: c, input, memory-management, malloc

I'm building a code to simulate the response of some dynamical systems for my PhD. Basically what I'm trying to do is:

1. Ask the user for the name of a input file that contains all parameters for the simulation;
2. Read the input file and assign each parameter to a specific variable in my program.
3. Do the calculations.

I'm having problems on step 2, as one of the values in the input file is the dimension `dim` of an dinamically allocated array `*x`.

Here is a working example of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_file(char *name, int *dim, double **x) {
    // Open input file
    FILE *input = fopen(name, "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        // Return error 
        perror(name);
        return;
    }
    // Read and assign system constants
    fscanf(input, "%i", dim);
    printf("dim = %i\n", *dim);
    // Allocate memory for x[dim]
    *x = malloc((*dim) * sizeof(*x));
    double y[(*dim)]; 
    printf("size of (*x) = %llu\n", sizeof(*x));
    printf("size of y = %llu\n", sizeof(y));
    // Security check for pointers
    if(*x == NULL) {
        free(*x);
        printf("Memory allocation for *x did not complete successfully\n");
        return;
    }
    // assign values to x[dim] vector
    for (int i = 0; i < *dim; i++) {
        fscanf(input, "%lf", &(*x)[i]);
        printf("(*x)[%i] = %lf\n", i, (*x)[i]);
    }
    // Close input file
    fclose(input);
}

char *get_input_filename(void) {
    char *filename = malloc(200 * sizeof(*filename));
    printf("Enter Input Filename: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    return filename;
}

int main (void) {

    int DIM;
    double *x = NULL;
    
    char *input_filename = get_input_filename();
    read_file(input_filename, &DIM, &x);

    printf("size of (*x) = %llu\n", sizeof(*x));
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        printf("(*x)[%i] = %lf\n", i, x[i]);
    }

    free(x); free(input_filename);
}
```

And here is the content of the input file `in.txt` for this example:

```
5
0.0 0.1 0.2 1.4 2.6
```

When I call `*x = malloc((*dim) * sizeof(*x));` I expected to find the dimension of the system to be `5 * 8bytes`, as the value for `*dim` is assigned in the previous line, however only `8 bytes` are allocated. Then, I declared the `y[(*dim)]` variable to check if the `sizeof` a `VLA` would behave in the same way as the `sizeof` `*x`, just to compare. The `sizeof(y)` was what I expected, but the `sizeof(*x)` wasn't, as shown in the output:

```
Enter Input Filename: in.txt
dim = 5
size of (*x) = 8
size of y = 40
(*x)[0] = 0.000000
(*x)[1] = 0.100000
(*x)[2] = 0.200000
(*x)[3] = 1.400000
(*x)[4] = 2.600000
size of (*x) = 8
(*x)[0] = 0.000000
(*x)[1] = 0.100000
(*x)[2] = 0.200000
(*x)[3] = 1.400000
(*x)[4] = 2.600000
```

I understand that it cannot allocate memory if the value of `*dim` is unknown, but a value is assigned in the previous line.

Also, I even don't know how the program assigned values to `(*x)` successfully as it don't have the necessary allocation of bytes to do it.

What am I missing here? How can I allocate the memory correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `*x = malloc((*dim) * sizeof(*x));` is wrong, should be `*x = malloc((*dim) * sizeof(**x));` (you got lucky because on your system `double` and `double*` have the same size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `dim` and `x` are *output* arguments; pointers that refer to locations where you're to store your results of this function (a size and a memory allocation sequence of `double` values).

This is where things are going off the rails:

```
*x = malloc((*dim) * sizeof(*x));
```

The left side is ok. And so is *most* of the right side. But if you're ever allocating to a pointer based on the size of the dereferenced data a pointer points to, you need to do so using just that: the size of the thing the pointer points to. `x` is a pointer-to-pointer, `*x` is a pointer, and the *latter* is the 'thing' we're allocating memory for, the address of which will be stored at `*x`.

Therefore, that should be:

```
*x = malloc((*dim) * sizeof **x);
```

Note: when I'm using *variables* as the operator argument for `sizeof` I personally strive *not* to use parens. It ensures I'm actually using a variable id rather than a type id, since the latter isn't allowed without parens. use what you favor at your discretion/whim.

More fundamental, however, your familiarity and understanding of `sizeof` is wrong and/or misled. You cannot acquire the size of dynamic-allocated memory region using `sizeof`. Using the `sizeof` operator on a pointer variable will give you *exactly* what you asked for: the size of the pointer variable (e.g. the size of a pointer). It is *your* responsibility to maintain and track magnitude of dynamic allocations (which, btw, your code does, using `dim`).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Indeed I was thinking that if I call `sizeof` after I multiplied it to `(*dim)` it would give me the allocated memory size of `size = (*dim)*(sizeof **x)`. As you said, I think the fundamental mistake was there. So if I want to check the size of the memory allocated region I have to print the whole expression as `printf("memory allocated = %llu\n", (*dim) * sizeof **x);`.